# Set different color to specifc items in QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `QListWidget` and I want to add border bottom to each item of the list and set a background color to items and I want to set to specific items a different background color.
So I used `my_list.setStyleSheet("QListWidget::item { border-bottom: 1px solid red; background-color: blue;}")` and to set background color to specific items I used `item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#E3E3E3"))`

The problem is the specif items that I set a different color don't get this color.

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: no, I didn't get errors.

Comment: OK, give me a minute — I'll try and reproduce. I've had this working before, so it *is* possible.

Comment: Updated — the problem wasn't what I thought. I think to do this you are going to need a custom delegate/widget in the list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use a combination of stylesheets and style settings on a widget — the stylesheet will override any settings on individual items. For example, the following code uses `setBackground` on each item to change the background colour.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

colors = [ '#7fc97f', '#beaed4', '#fdc086', '#ffff99', '#386cb0', '#f0027f', '#bf5b17', '#666666']

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        w = QListWidget()
        for n in range(8):
            i = QListWidgetItem('%s' % n)
            i.setBackground( QColor(colors[n]) )
            w.addItem(i)

        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        self.show()


app = QApplication([])
w = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

The resulting output:

[image]

However, if we add the stylesheet line in the result is (and second with only the bottom border):

[image]
[image]

Unfortunately, there is no way to set the border and the colour for the items. However, what you *can* do is either insert a custom widget as the list item, or [use an item delegate](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/pyqt4-qitemdelegate-example-with/) to draw the item. This gives you complete control over appearance, however you have to handle drawing yourself. Below is an example of doing this with a custom delegate:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

colors = [ '#7fc97f', '#beaed4', '#fdc086', '#ffff99', '#386cb0', '#f0027f', '#bf5b17', '#666666']


class MyDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent, *args)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter.save()

        # set background color
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.NoPen))
        if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
            # If the item is selected, always draw background red
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.red))
        else:
            c = index.data(Qt.DisplayRole+1) # Get the color
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(c)))

        # Draw the background rectangle            
        painter.drawRect(option.rect)

        # Draw the bottom border
        # option.rect is the shape of the item; top left bottom right
        # e.g. 0, 0, 256, 16 in the parent listwidget
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red))        
        painter.drawLine(option.rect.bottomLeft(), option.rect.bottomRight())

        # Draw the text
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black))
        text = index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
        # Adjust the rect (to pad)
        option.rect.setLeft(5)
        option.rect.setRight(option.rect.right()-5)
        painter.drawText(option.rect, Qt.AlignLeft, text)

        painter.restore()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        de = MyDelegate(self)
        w = QListWidget()
        w.setItemDelegate(de)
        for n in range(8):
            s = '%s' % n
            i = QListWidgetItem()
            i.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, s) # The label
            i.setData(Qt.DisplayRole+1, colors[n]) # The color
            w.addItem(i)

        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        self.show()


app = QApplication([])
w = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Which gives the following output:

[image]

The approach with delegates is to define a `paint` method, which accepts a `QPainter` object (with which you do the actual drawing), an `option` parameter containing the rectangle of the item (relative to the parent widget) and an `index` through which you can retrieve the item data. You then use the methods on the [QPainter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html) to draw your item.

In the example above we use this to pass in both the item label (at position `Qt.DisplayRole`) and the color in hex (at position `Qt.DisplayRole+1`). The name docs for [ItemDisplayRole](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) list the other defined data 'roles', but for most purposes you can ignore these.

Comment: @OussamaHe looks like the answer has been extended.

Comment: please can you help me to use an item delegate to draw the item because I visited the link before and I try to use delegate item but I didn't success, thank you in advance

Comment: @OussamaHe updated the answer with an example using `QItemDelegate`

Comment: thank you of the delegate example, if I want to add button to the item, how can I do it?

Comment: You can draw it in the painter, using `QStyleButton` but you will also then need to handle the clicking on the button (`QItemDelegate.editorEvent`). I can provide an example but can you open a new question? This is off-topic for the question asked.

Comment: I added the question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002223/customize-list-items-using-qitemdelegate